# How to make sure my subscription is ready before looking it up inside a helper?

Tags: meteor

I wish to do something very simple, namely to turn the value of a field in my database into a variable in my helper. The document looks like this:

```
{
  hero: "Simon Belmont",
  universe: "Castlevania",
  items: ["Whip", "Cross", "Oak Stake"]
}
```

In the helper, I want to do something similar to this:

```
var selectedHeroId = Session.get('whichHeroSelected')
var heroItems = Heroes.findOne({_id: selectedHero}).items
```

This, however, has turned out to be very fickle. At times it complains that `items` is not defined. Strangely, it works when I name the variable `items` but not when I name it `heroItems` or `itemsArray`.

So I'm looking for a way to make sure `Heroes` is subscribed to before looking stuff up in the database. I subscribe to it in Iron Router's `waitOn` function, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just need a [guard](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards):

```js
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  items: function() {
    var selectedHero = Heroes.findOne(Session.get('whichHeroSelected'));
    return selectedHero && selectedHero.items;
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice, but two things: 1) I'm not returning the data right away, I'm doing stuff with it before that. 2) According to the article, `waitOn` should fix this problem automatically. Why isn't this the case here?

Comment: The first thing was easily solvable, of course, by making `heroItems` a function that returns the same thing as you said. This fixes my problem completely, but I'm still curious about why `waitOn` doesn't work.

Comment: It should work, but I can't say why w/o seeing the `waitOn` code. Are you starting more than one subscription in it? If so, you'll need to return an array (this is a common problem).

Comment: Starting a massive amount of subscriptions using an array, yes. I have realized that it's most likely because they depend on Sessions, which in turn depend on stuff rendering in the DOM. I'm very happy with your solution and have begun to rewrite a lot of code using it! :)

Comment: Sounds complicated. I'd recommend using `waitOn` when it's actually important to block rendering because progressive updates don't make sense in your UI. In all other cases, I think using guards make more sense.